# C shifting all int bits sizeof int - 1 left and then right returns -1 for bit0= 1

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Using C I wanted to know if the first bit of an int x was 1 or 0, so I simply did something like this:

```
int y = (x<<(sizeof(int)*8)-1)>>((sizeof(int)*8)-1);
```

The thing is that when y is expected to be 0...01 it returns -1. But I tought the representation of -1 was 1...11. 
Why is happening that, since y is not full of ones, or is it?

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour for certain values. When shifting use unsigned types. And a byte is not guaranteed to have 8 bits. Either use `CHAR_BIT` or - better fixed-width integers from `stdint.h` (no need for `sizeof`). also "But I tought the representation of -1 was 1...11" is not guaranteed. It depends on your platform (it is on x86, ARM, PPC, MIPS, etc, though).

Comment: You are driving a nail with a screwdriver.  Please see CRoemheld answer, where the use of a hammer is described clearly.

Answer (score 1):

With the first bit you surely mean the LSB right? So assuming your binary number looks like

```
8 = 0001000
  MSB     LSB
```

Then you can simply check the LSB with

```
int set = x & 0x1;
```

If set is 0, then the LSB of X is 0, else 1.